# get names if count more then 2

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Doctors

```
"DoctorNumber"Doctor Name 
"1           "jack
"2           "smith
"3           "jay
```

Table patient

```
"patientName"DoctorNumber
"jonson     "1
"sarah      "1
"seyan      "2
"jackson    "3
```

out should be
the doctor name only
jack cause he have more then 2 patient

Comment: Surely you must have attempted something.  That should be part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you use a `JOIN` with `COUNT` in a `HANING` clause

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Doctors (
  `DoctorNumber` INTEGER,
  `DoctorName` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO Doctors
  (`DoctorNumber`, `DoctorName`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'jack'),
  ('2', 'smith'),
  ('3', 'jay');

CREATE TABLE Patients (
  `patientName` VARCHAR(7),
  `DoctorNumber` VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO Patients
  (`patientName`, `DoctorNumber`)
VALUES
  ('jonson', '1'),
  ('sarah', '1'),
  ('seyan', '"2'),
  ('jackson', '3');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
DoctorName FROM Doctors d INNER JOIN Patients p ON d.DoctorNumber = p.DoctorNumber
GROUP BY DoctorName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

| DoctorName |
| --- |
| jack |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/19)